puma-dev server error 'Unable to start worker'
I am trying to get puma-dev server working locally, and im hitting an issue. If I tail these logs tail -fn 2000 ~/Library/Logs/puma-dev.log I can see this error once I hit the first webpage and try to load
myapp-135b9fd1[92033]: [92508] ! Unable to start worker
myapp-135b9fd1[92033]: [92508] /Users/bsmith/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:329:in `allowed_with_path' 
mycase_app-135b9fd1[92033]: [92511] + Gemfile in context: /Users/bsmith/myapp/myapp/Gemfile

Before hitting the webpage, I can see these logs on puma-dev startup when tailing the logs. Seems like puma sort of boots of fine before trying to load an app, but not exactly sure.
2024/07/23 16:56:20 Existing valid puma-dev CA keypair found. Assuming previously trusted.
* Directory for apps: /Users/bsmith/.puma-dev
* Domains: test
* DNS Server port: 9253
* HTTP Server port: inherited from launchd
* HTTPS Server port: inherited from launchd
! Puma dev running...

This is on my local mac computer with an M1 chip, running Ventura 13.4.1. I use rbenv locally and am using ruby 3.2.2.
I tried installing puma-dev with a set of steps like this
brew install puma/puma/puma-dev
sudo puma-dev -setup
puma-dev -install -d test -timeout 1440m

I looked in the method where it is failing and saw this block of code in the path in the error above
def allowed_with_path
  return with_path { yield } if allow?
  raise GitError, "The git source #{uri} is not yet checked out. Please run "bundle install" before trying to start your application" 
end

The error being raised in this block never has its error message make it back to the puma logs, but I know that bundle install has run properly. I can spin up a rails console just fine and load models from the DB. Could there be some sort of integration between puma and my native git extensions that are causing issues here? Feels like this block of code erroring out has to do with checking out gems/branches/libraries, not exactly sure.
does anybody have any experience with this or have an idea of what part of puma is failing here?
I have tried re-installing puma-dev several times. I have tried setting a global rbenv version as well. I have tested normal git operations on the command line and can clone repos fine using SSH key with github.

Can you clarify what you mean by "...my native git extensions..."?
